# Execute expression on another IQueryable source

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

There are two classes with identical field structure: `WebMessage` and `WebMessageDto`.

I have a DataGrid which can work with both classes. And I have a RIA Service which can provide only `WebMessageDto` because `WebMessage` has navigation properties and they cannot be serialized.

Now, DataGrid should query RIA Service method returning `IQueryable<WebMessageDto>`. I need handle DataGrid's query and execute it on ORM's `Table<WebMessage>`, then transform result to `WebMessageDto` type and return it to DataGrid.

I started to implement custom IQueryable interface and I can handle expression.

```
public class WebMessageQueryContext
{
    // Executes the expression tree that is passed to it. 
    internal static object Execute(Expression expression, bool isEnumerable)
    {
        // DataContext.WebMessages is a ORM table which returns IQueryable<WebMessage>
        List<WebMessage> list = DataContext.WebMessages.Provider.Execute(expression);

        return WebMessageDto.ConvertFrom(list); // returning List<WebMessageDto>
    }
}
```

The code above will make recursive calls to this method. And I found microsoft's sample where queryable source changes in ExpressionVisitor and now I change original source to ORM's table.

```
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
    {
        if (c.Type == typeof(WebMessageDtoQuerySource<WebMessageDto>))
            return Expression.Constant(DataContext.WebMessages);

        return c;
    }
```

I'm getting exception when I execute the expression:

`Expression of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table'1[WebMessage]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'1[WebMessageDto]' of method 'Int32 Count[WebMessageDto](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebMessageDto])'`

There's no much information about IQueryableProviders and I don't know what to do... Who can answer, can I do it theoretically?

Comment: I can help you with that LINQ provider but I'm not convinced yet it is necessary. What exact static type does `this` have in your code above? Probably, not IQueryable but IEnumerable.

Comment: I work with devExpress GridControl and it binds to IQueryable collection to provide sorting/filtering/groupping. But there's limitation - GridControl can't work with Entities, it can work only with dtos.

Comment: The method `WebMessageDtos` loads all database rows in memory, makes convertion and after that external linq query executes. I need to load only necessary rows in memory and return them as dto.

Comment: @usr I suppose that the expression has link to it's original IQueryableProvider which contains `Execute` method listed above. Can I change the target of expression to WebMessages table?

Comment: Which Server Mode Data Source are you using? [Server Mode Concepts](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398)

Comment: Again, what type is `this`?

Comment: @usr `this` is ORM DataContext (DevExpress XPO)

Comment: @BrianR.Mullin I use RiaInstantFeedback. My RIA services should return `WebMessage`, but I cannot generate correct entity proxy because of Navigation Properties in `WebMessage` class. So I Decided to return `WebMessageDto`

Comment: What is an example of the query being passed to the RIA service?

Comment: @Justin It can be simple select _riaService.GetWebMessageDtoQuery().Take(20)

Comment: @JesseJames what do you mean by "The code above will make recursive calls to this method". Why don't you query on entities and make use of Cast<> operator on IQuereable to convert WebMessage to WebMessageDto? Again I can say that this problem does not require any customized Expression to be used.

Comment: It appears you are only changing the source from WebMessageDto to WebMessage. Any inputs are wrapped in parameters, which will need to be changed as well.  In addition, the Lambda expressions themselves will need their output type changed.  [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437239/change-a-linq-expression-predicate-from-one-type-to-another) shows a basic example. But if this is supposed to accept *any* query, you may have to implement every ExpressionVisitor method shown at [Microsoft's How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I was wrong. Before question edit I wrote that `Select` applied to `IQueryable` before `Where` causes loading all table rows in memory and then executing `Where` statement. But actually such behavior was caused by incorrect implementation of custom linq provider.

When I used datagrid without custom linq provider I mentioned that `Select` executes after `Where` even when `Select` is applied before `Where`.

In my code:

```
public IQueryable<WebMessageDto> Dtos 
{ 
    get { return db.WebMessages.Select(r => new WebMessageDto { Id = r.Id });} 
}
```

My DataGrid queries this method with `Where/OrderBy/GroupBy` statements and conversion to `WebMessageDto` occurs after them.

So, Alex Key's answer is also applicable.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted JesseJames.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [automapper](http://automapper.org/) to convert between your types.

Here is a [getting started guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

e.g.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();
OrderDto dto = Mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```

EDIT

You could use the [automapper IQueryable extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) to help.

Comment: He has no problem mapping. He could do that with a few assignments easily. He wants to run a query in the database that is running in memory at the moment.

Comment: Hmmm, but isn't that just because it's not pre-filtered? The filtering that could be applied to WebMessageDto is _likely_ to be a subset of that available to the WebMessage. So filter when it's WebMessage and then map to WebMessageDto?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need mapping. I can do it manually. I need to execute database query before mapping, not after.

Comment: @JesseJames - Are you trying to bring back a subset of the columns? do the IQueryable extensions help?

Comment: @AlexKey I did mapping and used extensions. `return DataContext.WebMessages.Project().To<WebMessageDto>()`. When DataGrid queries this method, it loads `all` rows from database, makes mapping, then query conditions apply. I need apply query conditions before mapping.